# Непонятное поведение кода!

Tags: c++, c

Уважаемые программисты! Возникла непонятная ситуация с фрагментом кода, взятым из книги Стивена Прата "Язык программирования C лекции и упражнения 6-ое издание", находящемся в 6-ой главе на странице 204 под названием "when.c". Сам фрагмент приведу ниже:

```
// when.c -- когда цикл завершается?
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream> 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); 
    int n = 5;
    while (n++ < 7); // строка 7
    {
        printf("n = %d\n", n);
        n++; // строка 10
        printf("Теперь n = %d\n", n); // строка 11 
    }
    printf("Цикл завершен.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Скомпилировал я его в Visual Studio 2019 на C++ (Ведь C и C++ должны быть совместимы). Странность заключается в том, что когда идет проверка условия в операторе While, к переменной n прибавляется единица до тех пор, пока она не станет равна 7, когда как в книге, кстати тоже непонятно мне почему, прибавления в первой итерации вообще не происходит, сейчас покажу вывод программы, описанный в книге:

```
n = 5
Теперь n = 6 
n = 6
Теперь n = 7 
Цикл завершен.
```

В то время как у меня вывод программы выглядит так:

```
n = 8
Теперь n = 9
Цикл завершен.
```

Короче говоря, помогите пожалуйста разобраться в этом :) !

Comment: Лишняя `;`, только и всего...

Comment: В 9-ой строчке? :(

Comment: Но ведь в листинге написано именно так ( в книге то есть) очень странно, видимо опечатка

Comment: Да и вывод судя по всему в книге тоже неправильный, так выходит?

Comment: После `while(...)`

Comment: Вот как у него в оригинале: https://ibb.co/dr0cTZ3 В переводе — да, сделали ошибку. Можете смело писать в "Диалектику" об обнаруженной ошибке. Там точка с запятой не нужна.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам!

Comment: Мне очень сильно кажется, что в книге неправильный вывод. Мы же в условии цикла используем постфиксный инкремент. То есть в условии n = 5, но в теле цикла n = 6, а значит и выведет 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (n++ < 7);
               ^ - что делает?
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/702086)

Comment: @Dmitry является ответом на вопрос

Comment: Это вопрос же, нет. Что делает `;`?

Comment: @Dmitry, это однозначно ответ в форме наводящего вопроса

Comment: @avp отличный ответ, чего уж